# VMWare Player won't open a virtual machine/ Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I've created an Arch Linux virtual machine, and VMWare Player will not open it when I click "File -> Open a Virtual Machine -> arch.vmx (the name of the machine)". I found an official tutorial on the subject, and according to it I have made no errors in my attempt to open the machine. I'm not sure whether this is simply a bug or a mistake on my part.

Comment: "I have made no errors in my attempt to open the machine", had to say as we weren't there. Anyways how was it set up and any error messages shown?

Comment: Based on my readings of the above-mentioned tutorial and comparing what I did to what the tutorial said to do, I don't think I made any errors. And no, no error messages were shown. It simply didn't add the machine to the list.